# Links bunching up in Safari

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am making a new website, and I am using Dreamweaver. A problem I am running into is my links are bunching up in safari. Here is what it looks like in **Firefox**

### [image: View in Firefox]

and its good BUT unfortunately here is what it looks like in **Safari**

[image: View in Safari]

I am using Dreamweaver to develop the websit and CSS of above page looks like this

```
#header {
    background-image: url(bg02.jpg);
    height: 10em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0em;
    margin-top: -2em;
    margin-right: 0em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    margin-left: 0em;
    width: auto;
}

#header h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    padding-top: 0.4em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    padding-left: 0.8em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

#header a {
    color: #468CEA;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: compact;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: -2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Anyways hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot for looking at this!

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle?

Comment: change  to `display: inline-block` in **header a** style

Comment: and btw Dreamweaver have nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `display: compact` (this is hardly supported), try `display: inline-block` and then play with the padding:

```
#header a {
    color: #468CEA;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px; /* Change this to whatever suits your needs */
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: -2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```